# What does Array.map.bind(Array) represent?

Tags: javascript

This is a piece of code from redux script.

```
const print = compose(
        list => console.log(list),
        titles => titles.join(", "),
        map => map(c=>c.title),
        colors => colors.map.bind(colors),
        state => state.colors
      )
```

In the above function, what does `colors.map.bind(colors)` do? If I comment that line, I am getting this error:

> map is not a function.

Comment: map is not a function occurs because `colors` is not an array. Check datatype of colors.

Comment: No. colors is an array.

Comment: `colors.map.bind(colors)` returns a `map` function bound to the `colors` array. Just `colors.map` would return the `map` prototype implementation with no association to `colors`.

Comment: Thank you @deceze. That answered my question